# Buttons don't work on iPad with Google Sheets - the onEdit(e) workaround isn't working. Suggestions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, mobile, ipad

I have a button that works with the function `Yeah_Go()`, but only when using it on a browser on a laptop. When I try to press the button on an iPad Google Sheets mobile app, it doesn't work. Instead, the drawing is selected and moveable. Not my intention, eh?

`Yeah_Go()` works properly when you call it directly from the imported macros list, basically, a verify alert Okay_Cancel that leads to another function.

Apparently, button nonfunction is a known challenge on iPads.

It has been suggested to try the `onEdit(e)` function thus:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  console.log("Function triggered");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange("J17").getValue();
  if (r == "TRUE") {
    Yeah_Go();
  }
}
```

When I check the checkbox in J17, nothing happens. Similarly, when I run the macro from the list of imported macros, nothing happens. Not even a happy note in the console...

How can I improve this so it actually works?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event object fields are text strings, but if you use `.getRange().getValue()` to get the real value in a cell, the possible values of a checkbox cell with default settings are the Booleans `true` and `false` rather than the text strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`.

To make your script work, take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.value === 'TRUE' && e.range.getA1Notation() === 'J17') {
    Yeah_Go();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
This absolutely works in Google sheets on a browser. However, Yeah_Go only half works. It won't bring up the alert box on an iPad, even though this system works exactly as you suggest it should on a browser on my desktop. Not sure why. I'd be grateful for suggestions.

Comment: `function Yeah_Go() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SORT_FORM = ss.getSheetByName("SORT FORM");
  var checkbox1 = SORT_FORM.getRange("H10").getValue(); // Ready to import
  var checkbox2 = SORT_FORM.getRange("H33").getValue(); // Data Verified
`

Comment: `
  if (checkbox1 && checkbox2) {
    // Both checkboxes are checked, so proceed with function
    Transfer_Sort_Form_To_DB();
  } else {
    // One or both checkboxes are not checked, display alert message
   SORT_FORM.getRange('H17').setValue('FALSE'); // Uncheck "Import to DB"
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert('Please check both "Ready to Import" and "Data Verified" first.');
  }
}`

Comment: Google Apps Script runs on Google's servers rather than your end device. The various [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) methods only work with web browser clients. To build a custom user interface that works in the Sheets App in your end device as well, you need to create a [Workspace Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-workspace-addons). There is a learning curve. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Thanks @doubleunary, I'll check it out!